# Unable to intercept the advice method in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am implementing custom annotation processing using Spring AOP. I have below code.

```
public class CacheDemo  {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         applicationContext =
               new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
    }
  }
```

//Application Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("Demo")
@Component
public class ApplicationConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    TestCacheDemo testCacheDemo;
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {

        applicationContext = ctx;
    }
   
    @Bean
    public void testCacheDemoIntialize()
    {
        testCacheDemo.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        testCacheDemo.test();
    }
}
```

//CustomAnnotation processor

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomAnnotationAspect {

    @Autowired
    private AbstractCacheService cacheService;

    @Around("@annotation(Demo.CustomCacheable)")
    public Object customCacheable(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable { // This method is not called at all

       joinPoint.proceed();

      // Some other code to follow

}
```

// Custom Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CustomCacheable {

}
```

// Annotation user

```
 @Component
public class CacheProvider
{
    @Autowired
    AbstractCacheService abstractCacheService;
    CacheManager<String,String> cacheManager;


    @PostConstruct
    void init()
    {
        cacheManager = CreateCache.create(s -> {return s.toUpperCase();});
        abstractCacheService.setCacheManager(cacheManager);

    }

    @CustomCacheable
    String getCacheValue(String s)
    {
        String str=s.toUpperCase();
        return str;
    }

}
```

For testing purpose I have created the below bean

```
@Component
public class TestCacheDemo extends TimerTask
{
    private  ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private Timer timer;
    @Autowired
    CacheProvider cacheProvider;
    void test()
    {
        System.out.println("Called test");
        for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }

        //CacheProvider cacheProvider = applicationContext.getBean(CacheProvider.class);
        //cacheProvider.getCacheValue("Hello");

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(this,1000,3000);
    }
    void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx)
    {
        applicationContext=ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        cacheProvider.getCacheValue("Hi");
    }
}
```

Whenever the application is started it will call the test method of the TestCacheDemo Class and sets the timer to be fired after 3 secs so that I can call the annotated method getCacheValue from inside the run method of the timer task. But when the annotated method is called the annotation processor is not invoked. Hence I am unable to do annotation processing. Please let me know where is the problem?

Comment: But it works when you don't use timer? I mean when you uncomment commented line in your code

Comment: is AOP is enabled? Add @EnableAspectJAutoProxy above configuration class if not.

Comment: check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495320/spring-aop-aspect-not-triggered-in-thread

Comment: Also check this @annotation(Demo.CustomCacheable) does your package start with capital word?

Comment: it worked after adding EnableAspectJProxy anntation. Thanks @Sachin

Comment: It also worked by removing the comments at line cacheProvider.getCacheValue("Hello"); Thanks @tashkhisi

Answer (score 0):

To use AspectJ in spring boot you must enable it.
You should add the following annotation to your application main class (CacheDemo) or application configuration class.

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
```